# Ground Cover Identification

Tags: identification, ground-cover

[image]What type of ground cover is this?  Is it a weed?  Very low growing in patches on my lawn.

Answer (score 1):

We call it "creeping charlie" and it is a very invasive, pernicious weed. The botanical name is Glechoma hederacea.Creeping Charlie [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZ4F.jpg). It spreads very quickly and easily, it has small purple flowers. Leaf shape may vary some but that is Creeping Charlie, here's another picture of it in bloom.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZ4F.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZ4F.jpg)

Comment: Wow!  Its a weed.  But I actually like it!  Any harm to grow it as a ground cover in between stepping stones?  Or do you recommend something else?  Thank you!

Comment: There is no "harm" in growing it in between stepping stones, the problem is confining it to where you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks nothing like the creeping charlie in my lawn - wrong color and growth habit. It may be the very small, invasive Geranium lucidum. If so, the flowers will be pink: https://www.kingcounty.gov/services/environment/animals-and-plants/noxious-weeds/weed-identification/shiny-geranium.aspx.